# Cannot receive background fcm background message on flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to receive data-only fcm message in flutter.
Platform: android 13

it shows message

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver(23619): broadcast received for message. 
E/FLTFireBGExecutor(23619): Background isolate already started. 
I/FLTFireMsgService(23619): Service has not yet started, messages will be queued.
```

My Code :

```dart
@pragma("vm:entry-point")
Future<void> _messageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("Received ${message.toMap()}");
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_messageHandler);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I couldn't figure out what's wrong with my code

Answer (score 1):

Issue reported to firebase team
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9932

Here is my sample code and works
https://github.com/krupikivan/firebase_notification_background

Comment: well, the issue happens only in fcm 14.1.0 for me, I just downgraded fcm to 14.0.4 ._.

Comment: They just upgrade to version 14.1.1